# Importing data from DBeaver to applications like PowerBi

Tags: mysql, sql, automation, powerbi-desktop, dbeaver

Is it possible to import data from DBeaver? We use DBeaver to manage our dataset but I'd like to prevent having to manually export data into a file and then go into Power BI to import that file. 1) this is tedious, and 2) the report generated is a 'snapshot' and the export/import will need to be repeated periodically to  make sure the data is up to to date.

Comment: write a shell sript that runs mysqldump periodically